# Javascript performance issue with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

We are having performance issues with that code.It works in loop with 150 times.

That code work for betting, matches have empty bet fields on screen.Then that code works for fill winner odds with looking and comparing scores.

In example, if match finished with 1-0 home team win, i must write "MS1" on screen.And for making that, i must get score info using jQuery attr selector.

In the weekends, there are a lot of matches and it is crashing or it works too slow :/

Have you any ideas to work faster?

```
OddEngine = function(odd)
{
    $("#matchCode_" + odd.ID).html(odd.C);
    $("#match_" + odd.ID).attr("code",odd.C);
    var status = $("#match_" + odd.ID).attr("status");
    if (status == 1)
        return;

    var htscore = $("#othomeTeamScore_"+odd.ID).html();
    var atscore = $("#otawayTeamScore_"+odd.ID).html();
    var iy_htscore = $("#homeTeamHalfScore_"+odd.ID).html();
    var iy_atscore = $("#awayTeamHalfScore_"+odd.ID).html();



    for (var i = 0; i < odd.Odds.length; i++) {
        var bet = odd.Odds[i];

         var winnerMsOdd = 'F.X';
          var winnerMsTitle =  'X';
          if (htscore > atscore)
          {
            winnerMsOdd = 'F.1';
            winnerMsTitle = '1';
          }
          else if (htscore < atscore)
          {
            winnerMsOdd = 'F.2';
            winnerMsTitle = '2';
          }

          $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddcode='MS']").html(bet[winnerMsOdd]);
          $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='MS']").fadeIn();
          $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='MS']").html(winnerMsTitle);


          if (currentSportId != 3)
          {
                var winnerIyOdd = 'S.X';
                var winnerIyTitle =  'X';
                if (iy_htscore > iy_atscore)
                {
                    winnerIyOdd = 'S.1';
                    winnerIyTitle = '1';
                }
                else if (iy_htscore < iy_atscore)
                {
                    winnerIyOdd = 'S.2';
                    winnerIyTitle = '2';
                }

                if (bet[winnerIyOdd])
                {
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddcode='IY']").html(bet[winnerIyOdd]);
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='IY']").fadeIn();
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='IY']").html(winnerIyTitle);
                }

          }

          if (currentSportId == 1)
          {
                var winnerAuOdd = 'UNDER';
                if (parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) > 2.5)
                {
                winnerAuOdd = 'OVER';
                }

                if (bet[winnerAuOdd])
                {
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddcode='AU']").html(bet[winnerAuOdd]);
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='AU']").fadeIn();
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='AU']").html(winnerAuOdd == 'UNDER' ? 'ALT' : 'ÜST');

                }

                var winnerTGOdd = 'GS.01';
                var winnerTGtitle = "0-1";
                if (parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) > 1 && parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) < 4)
                {
                    winnerTGOdd = 'GS.23';
                    winnerTGtitle = "2-3";
                }
                else if (parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) > 3 && parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) < 7)
                {
                    winnerTGOdd = 'GS.46';
                    winnerTGtitle = "4-6";
                }
                else if (parseInt(htscore) + parseInt(atscore) >= 7)
                {
                    winnerTGOdd = 'GS.7P';
                    winnerTGtitle = "7+";
                }


                if (bet[winnerTGOdd])
                {
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddcode='TG']").html(bet[winnerTGOdd]);
                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='TG']").fadeIn();

                    $("#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='TG']").html(winnerTGtitle);
                }
          }
    }

    $("#msOdd_" + odd.ID).html(odd.C);
    if (currentSportId == 1 || currentSportId == 2 || currentSportId == 7)
    {
        $("#htOdd_" + odd.ID).html(odd.Odds["F.1"]);
    }
    $("#uOdd_"  + odd.ID).html(odd.C);
    $("#tOdd_"  + odd.ID).html(odd.C);




}
```

Comment: Move all the layout code out of that loop and you'll boost performance. All those `fade` and `html` calls are **VERY** costly.

Comment: Are your IDs unique throughout the page? `"#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddcode='MS']"` and `"#match_"+odd.ID+" [oddtag='MS']"` should always be the same element.

Comment: @TorstenWalter Perhaps replace the `.html` with `.text` whenever possible? And add a class to the element, and fade them all in at once outside the loop?

Comment: re-selecting the same element over and over is also costly.

Comment: The costly thing is that `html` and `fade` both cause the browser to recalculate the layout, as does `text`, also the attribute selectors are as slow as it can get. A good starting point would be to fetch all `[oddtag='MS']` elements beforehand and then fetch the `odd.ID` element _once_ for each iteration and then doing all the work.

Comment: Please show us your HTML so we can see how the structure of the HTML can be used to simplify all your selector operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of bad stuff in there:

Issues:

- You are hammering away at the DOM repeatedly. This is unavoidable but you don't need to do as much as you are doing. A lot of the remaining points follow-up on how to avoid.
- You're using attribute selectors. These are slow and don't have native methods to support in most non-XML scenarios so are going to force a lot more work out of the interpreter. Try as classes instead. You can have multiple classes and add/remove with jQuery addClass and removeClass functions without interfering with other classes. If you're supporting IE8, narrow down to nearest ID and use a tag selector with a class.
- You're not caching any of your JQ selectors. $('#someId') does a bit of work (although is faster than just about anything else. If it's going to get re-used, assign to a var. Convention is: var `$someId = $('#someId');` so you know it's a jqObject. This repeatedly: `$('#someId <other stuff>)` is probably slower than this: `$someId.find(<otherstuff>)` repeatedly. In your case, assuming odd.id is unique, you'd at least want: `var $matchHtml = $("#matchCode_" + odd.ID)` at the top of the loop.
- You're doing a ton of UI stuff as you go. Consider building the collections you need and then handling it all at once after the loop. e.g. building two JQ objects for AU and TG (see the 'add' method) and then hitting them with the functionality they need once the loop is complete.
- This is probably less of a big deal than the JQ stuff but you're using a lot of '.' operators unnecessarily. Every '.' does actually represent some work and in some cases actually represent getters like length which can do a fair bit more work since they have to count up the array elements. Here's the hyper-anal loop which also has the nice side-effect of being more concise:

```
var myOdds = odd.Odds,
i=myOdds.length;

//if order matters, this goes backwards. Easy fix: myOdds.reverse

while(i--){
    thisOdds = myOdds[i];//if you're using thisOdds more than once
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could the '#match'+odd.ID node and key all your node searches within the loop from this node. eg. matchOdd.find( '[oddcode="MS"]' ), this should improve the performance against querying the DOM.

As for improving performance in the loop you could consider making it async by delegating to setTimeout. Here is a link to a resource that explains how to approach this http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2009/07/03/not-blocking-the-ui-in-tight-javascript-loops